# Code coverage do not include code covered with UITests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-coverage, xcode-ui-testing

In my simple app I have a few files that are tested by unit testing and uitesting.

[image]

I am **pretty sure** that in `UITests` I tested **EVERY line** in `WLLoginViewController`. The test passed, but it is not considered as 100% in code coverage for that file. Sometimes when I restart Xcode, run app again, clean app, hard clean app. Do some accidental things, it works. But run tests once again, and again it is not considered. Why? Any ideas how to fix it? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, sometimes Xcode says that you are testing 100% of your code and sometimes it doesn't. So it's really inconsistent. That is an indicator for a bug.

Since you are still using an Xcode-beta, it's most likely a bug in Xcode. I wouldn't worry to much since it's still a beta-version and would check later, when the final version is released.

Comment: Another hint is that coverage permanently do not include any file from `UITests`, but works fine with unit tests. :-) Is it possible? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found temporary workaround.

1. Remove derived data for your project (*window->projects*)
2. Quit Xcode and Simulator.
3. Launch Xcode with your project, and run tests.
4. Run tests again.

Remember to wait until indexing is finished:

[image]

Weird, but try and see:)